# Animation of a sandpile: why does calling this function in a while loop break my animation? Does animation.FuncAnimation behave like a for loop?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, animation, seaborn

I am trying to create an animation of an [abelian sandpile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_sandpile_model) using seaborn and numpy arrays in Python3.

First I import all necessary libraries

```
%matplotlib notebook #for running this program in a jupyter notebook
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import seaborn as sns
import random
```

Then I set the dimension of the array, the number of iterations, and the maximum value for any cell in the array and initialize a numpy array of zeros:

```
dimension = 3
iterations = 100
Z_critical = 4

Z = np.zeros((dimension, dimension))
```

Afterwards, I define a function to simulate "avalanches" in the sandpile. For those note familiar with abelian sandpiles, just consider this an arbitary transformation of the array Z which when applied over and over yields a matrix whose cells all contain integer values less than Z_critical:

```
def avalanch(Z, Z_critical):
    Z_new = np.copy(Z)
    repeat = False
    for x in range(dimension):
        for y in range(dimension):
            if x < dimension-1 and Z[x+1, y] >= Z_critical:
                Z_new[x, y] = Z_new[x, y] + 1
                Z_new[x+1, y] = 0
                repeat = True
            if y < dimension-1 and Z[x, y+1] >= Z_critical:
                Z_new[x, y] = Z_new[x, y] + 1
                Z_new[x, y+1] = 0
                repeat = True
            if x > 0 and Z[x-1, y] >= Z_critical:
                Z_new[x, y] = Z_new[x, y] + 1
                Z_new[x-1, y] = 0
                repeat = True
            if y > 0 and Z[x, y-1] >= Z_critical:
                Z_new[x, y] = Z_new[x, y] + 1
                Z_new[x, y-1] = 0
                repeat = True
    return(Z_new, repeat)
```

As a sidenote, I'm curious as to rather there is a way to "vectorize" this bit of the code to make it run faster.

Now I would like to increment the center of the array by 1 and then call the avalanch function until all values in the array are less than Z_critical. The program works just fine when all I do is output a heatmap for every iteration:

```
for i in range(iterations):
    x=1
    y=1
    Z[x, y] = Z[x, y] + 1
    repeat = True
    while repeat == True:
        Z, repeat = avalanch(Z, Z_critical)
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax = sns.heatmap(Z, square = True, cbar = False, vmin=0, vmax=4)
plt.show(ax)
```

**But here is the broken bit. When I try to animate it I only get 4 frames before the animation pauses** (though my kernel remains busy for a little longer, suggesting that the underlying transformations of the matrix are still being carried out?).

```
fig = plt.figure()

def animate(i, Z, Z_critical):
    plt.clf()
enter code here
    x=1
    y=1
    Z[x, y] = Z[x, y] + 1
    Z, repeat = avalanch(Z, Z_critical)
    while repeat == True:
        Z, repeat = avalanch(Z, Z_critical)
    ax = sns.heatmap(Z, square = True, cbar = False, vmin=0, vmax=4)


anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, fargs=(Z, Z_critical), frames=iterations, repeat = False)
```

I have been conseptualizing the animation.Funcanimation() as working pretty much like a for loop but that must be wrong. *How do I modify my code such that I get an animation whose frames look like the heatmap plots from my working code?*

While debugging, I confirmed that I can get a working animation of much longer than four frames by using a different animation function that just changes the value of the middle cell between 0 and 3 using:

```
def animate(i, Z, Z_critical):
    plt.clf()
    x=1
    y=1
    Z[x, y] = np.mod(Z[x, y] + 1, Z_critical)
    ax = sns.heatmap(Z, square = True, cbar = False, vmin=0, vmax=4)
```

***So it seems as if it is the calling of the avalanch function which is somehow broken. The avalanch function works in the for loop but not under iteration in the animation.***

For convenience, here is the entire code that I am currently playing with in one snippet:

```
%matplotlib notebook
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import seaborn as sns
import random

dimension = 3
iterations = 100
Z_critical = 4

Z = np.zeros((dimension, dimension))

def avalanch(Z, Z_critical):
    Z_new = np.copy(Z)
    repeat = False
    for x in range(dimension):
        for y in range(dimension):
            if x < dimension-1 and Z[x+1, y] >= Z_critical:
                Z_new[x, y] = Z_new[x, y] + 1
                Z_new[x+1, y] = 0
                repeat = True
            if y < dimension-1 and Z[x, y+1] >= Z_critical:
                Z_new[x, y] = Z_new[x, y] + 1
                Z_new[x, y+1] = 0
                repeat = True
            if x > 0 and Z[x-1, y] >= Z_critical:
                Z_new[x, y] = Z_new[x, y] + 1
                Z_new[x-1, y] = 0
                repeat = True
            if y > 0 and Z[x, y-1] >= Z_critical:
                Z_new[x, y] = Z_new[x, y] + 1
                Z_new[x, y-1] = 0
                repeat = True
    return(Z_new, repeat)

fig = plt.figure()

def animate(i, Z, Z_critical):
    plt.clf()
    #x = random.randrange(0, dimension)
    #y = random.randrange(0, dimension)
    x=1
    y=1
    Z[x, y] = Z[x, y] + 1
    Z, repeat = avalanch(Z, Z_critical)
    while repeat == True:
        Z, repeat = avalanch(Z, Z_critical)
    ax = sns.heatmap(Z, square = True, cbar = False, vmin=0, vmax=4)


anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, fargs=(Z, Z_critical), frames=iterations, repeat = False)
```

Comment: Of course it is rather inefficient to create a new heatmap in each step; however, the main point seems to be that from the fourth iteration onwards, the data is always the same and doesn't change anymore. –

Comment: Is creating a new heatmap each step not required to generate each frame of the animation (is there a way to change the individual colors of cells in the heatmap?). The thing is that the data does chang after the fourth iteration onwards in the "for loop" version (fourth cell) so my misunderstanding is how the FuncAnimation() works differently than the for loop with regards to the data transformation.